# How to format number using intl-tel-input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, intl-tel-input

I have included `intl-tel-input` js & css library in my `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/14.0.6/css/intlTelInput.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/14.0.6/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
```

I have another file called `app.js` which inside of it I format number while user is typing in a `textbox`:

```
window.intlTelInputGlobals.loadUtils(_TEL_INPUT_UTILS).then(function(x, y){

var pn = $("#phone_number")[0];
var iti = intlTelInput(pn,{
    nationalMode: false,
    initialCountry: 'US'
})
var handleChangeVerification = function() {
if(iti.getNumber() ){
    iti.setNumber(iti.getNumber());
}};
pn.addEventListener('change', handleChangeVerification);
pn.addEventListener('keyup', handleChangeVerification);
```

The variable `_TEL_INPUT_UTILS` refers to the utility script of `intl-tel-input` after it's loaded I try to format number in my `text box`.

This code resides in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //...
})
```

Now I have a code in `app.js` that is outside of `loadUtils` and I want to format that number in a variable.

When I call the same `loadUtils`, I get an error of:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: window.intlTelInputGlobals.loadUtils(...) is null my_scpecific_funcation@webpack:///./src/app.js?:258:13
```

**The question is that** how can I format the number inside of a variable? Do I need to use `loadUtils` each time? Is there a better way for the whole process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing I didn't know about was that when you use `loadUtils`, It will be loaded and you will have access to it.

So I used the below code without further ado:

```
intlTelInputUtils.formatNumber(my_number_var, null, intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
```